# Поисковик Google не ранжирует главную страницу сайта

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

Всем привет, есть сайт [Fotonejnaya.com](https://fotonejnaya.com). В гугл поиске показывает на 4й странице внутреннюю ссылку. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Самый простой вариант для начала, обратите внимание на тег `<title>` и
   целевую страницу. Сейчас в теге нет прямого вхождения запроса "фотограф в барселоне". Задайте себе вопрос, какой странице может соответствовать этот запрос?
2. Подключите Google Search Console.
3. Проведите технический аудит сайта.